# How can you determine which submit button was pressed, when the name attributes are in an array?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Consider:

```
echo "<form action='edit.php' method='post'>";

while ($display = mysqli_fetch_assoc($newArticles)) {
                    ....
  echo "<input type='submit' class='col-sm-offset-5 btn btn-default' name='delete[]' value='Delete article'>" .
       "<input type='submit' class='col-sm-offset-1 btn btn-default' name='edit[]' value='Edit Article'>" ."<br/>"
                    ....
}
echo "</form>
```

After the iterations are finished I end up with several panels that have both delete and edit buttons inside. I was searching for solutions on how to distinguish between their names, and found that I could add them in an array.

Now I have unique values for all of the name attributes. How can I determine which one of them was pressed? Should I go for a different approach?

Comment: What output does `var_dump($_POST);` in `edit.php` gives you ?

Comment: array(5) { ["name"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(16) "Hristiyan Anev\\" [1]=> string(11) "Lorem Ipsum" [2]=> string(16) "James Goosling\\" } ["article"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(3567)
This is the array from the last panel. @Nirnae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When clicking on a submit-button, only the clicked submit-button are sent with post-request to php (the server). Therefore keep the same name (no array) on the submit-buttons and check which button has been sent by checking the value of the submit-button.

**Something like:**

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submitaction'] == 'Delete article') {
    //action for delete
} 
if ($_POST['submitaction'] == 'Edit Article') 
{
    //action for edit
} 

//Your code
   echo "<form action='edit.php' method='post'>";
      while ($display = mysqli_fetch_assoc($newArticles)) {
                          ....
        echo "<input type='submit' class='col-sm-offset-5 
        btn btn-default' name='submitaction' value='Delete article'>" .
             "<input type='submit' class='col-sm-offset-1 btn 
        btn-default' name='submitaction' value='Edit Article'>" ."<br/>"
                          ....
      }  
    echo "</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! The problem is that it is not working like that for me. When I do $_POST['name'] (because I have a hidden input with name='name') I get the first name from the pannel, not the one that I clicked? Here's my github if you want to see the whole code: https://github.com/batristio/FITCoursework

Comment: Why not make several forms? (instead of putting <form> and </form> outside of the loop you put it inside. (looking at home.php). If you do that you won't have to make array input-fields.

Comment: It is working now. The opening <form> and closing </form> should be inside the loop. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear!  Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it would be to use the id obtained from your query and insert them in your HTML elements.

For example :

```
while ($display = mysqli_fetch_assoc($newArticles)) {
    echo "<input type='submit' class='col-sm-offset-5 btn btn-default' name='delete".$newArticles['id']."[]' value='Delete article'>";

  }
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question to 100%? How would you determine which button is clicked?